# Usage of the word "explorer" - need advice

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I would like to combine the words "event" and "explorer" to "eventexplorer". But I am actually not sure if that works.

Can I use this combination to describe something like "people who discover new events"?

English is not my mother language, therefore the question.

Comment: English typically separates ad-hoc noun–noun compounds with spaces or sometimes hyphens; it does not just run them together as you have done. Also, *advice* is not a count noun, and so does not take an indefinite article suggests it can be counted.

Comment: What's the purpose of exploring events? You need to be more specific. Party goers are those who like to go to parties. Event explorer? I don't think event itself is something you explore.

Comment: "event scout" (*scout* is often used in the *talent scout* expression, it is a person sent out to explore an area, to obtain information, to make a search ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Event explorer" would be the usual way to combine nouns in this way.  "Event" becomes a noun modifier of "explorer."  Similar phrases:  car rider; house hunter; pet owner, truck owner; paper shuffler; food critic; tax collector.

Some compound words contain hyphens, though I can't think of any in this same object-agent pattern as above.  Mother-in-law, self-conscious, African-American.

When one of the former (noun modifier followed by agent) becomes sufficiently common, it may merge into one word:  taxman, partygoer, cowboy, sightseer (though I think sight-seer works), headhunter, breadwinner.

Since "eventexplorer" is a new word (whatever it may mean), people reading it will either think you made a mistake leaving out the space, or that your English is not good.  I'd say "event explorer" is the way to go.  (In terms of spelling -- like Rathony, I don't know think the meaning is clear.)