# Are either of the phrases "African-American individuals" or "European-American individuals" hyphenated?

Tags: american-english, hyphenation, north-american-english, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

This is in American English, but if it is different in British English, it is worth a mention.

Comment: AFAIK compound adjectives implying descent from, or association with, two different countries or nationalities are, or can be, hyphenated in all varieties of English (e.g. _Anglo-French, Italian-American_).

Comment: See [hyphen in 'a much-needed physiological understanding of...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/607099/hyphen-in-a-much-needed-physiological-understanding-of/607111#607111) and  [usage of the word 'explorer- ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277664/usage-of-the-word-explorer-need-advice/277668#277668).

Comment: Most editors would change that to "African Americans" and "European Americans". What does "individuals" add other than a punctuation complication?

Comment: @Tim "individuals" happens to be needed in context. However, I agree that the hyphen for African American does not need to be kept.

Comment: @BigMistake Hard to imagine that context, since there's no difference between Canadians and Canadian individuals,  to use an other example, other than the latter being wordy and clunky.

Comment: @Tim It's needed for certain fields.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use it.

> “African American” spelled open or hyphenated has generated heated debate over the years. Some people regard the hyphen as bias. But since the hyphen doesn’t improve understanding of the terms, it may be removed unless a publisher needs it.”
>
> African American is not to be hyphenated as a noun phrase. For instance, he is an African American. As an adjective, you can hyphenate it. The reason is that a compound adjective is always hyphenated before a noun. For example, he loves African-American literature. However, African American (not hyphenated) is allowed when Black individuals or groups prefer it.

[Michnews](https://www.michnews.com/is-african-american-hyphenated/)

Comment: Yes, this is why I was wondering. African American is often not hyphenated, but I am not sure if this applies to European American.